# The metadata could not be determined because statement 'insert into

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a select statement, where I have created 2 temp tables and doing an insert into select before taking the data from those temp tables creating a join between them. This final select is what I want the metadata to be. In ssms it runs fine, in ssis I don't know why its throwing that error. Query is as such:

```
CREATE TABLE #Per (PerID bigint NOT NULL......)
CREATE TABLE #Pre (PerID bigint NOT NULL, IsWorking.......)
INSERT INTO #Per SELECT .... FROM .....
INSERT INTO #Pre SELECT .... FROM .....
SELECT * FROM #Per per LEFT JOIN #Pre pre ON per.PerID = pre.PerID
```

I have tested all the statements to make sure they work and the query as a whole and it returns me the data, but ssis is throwing the error:

```
The metadata could not be determined because statement 'INSERT INTO #Per SELECT ...... uses a temp table.".
Error at project_name [646]: Unable to retrieve column information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the database is available.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using a table variable instead something like:

```
DECLARE @Per TABLE (PerID bigint NOT NULL......)
DECLARE @Pre TABLE (PerID bigint NOT NULL, IsWorking.......)
INSERT INTO @Per SELECT .... FROM .....
INSERT INTO @Pre SELECT .... FROM .....
SELECT * FROM @Per per LEFT JOIN @Pre pre ON per.PerID = pre.PerID
```

Should work fine

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on SSIS 2012 or later versions, then it uses system stored procedure **sp_describe_first_result_set** to fetch the metadata of the tables and it does not support temporary tables. 
But you can use other options like table variables and CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running the query directly, but if you wrap it in a stored procedure you can use result sets.  When you execute the stored procedure use WITH RESULT SETS to define the returning data.

EXECUTE dbo.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE
WITH RESULT SETS(
COLUMN1 DATA_TYPE,
COLUMN2 DATA_TYPE,
...
)