# Get only one column from stored procedure using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to select only one column from a stored procedure that I didn't write, I'm just a consumer.

When I execute this code for example:

```
SELECT ID
FROM OPENROWSET('MSOLEDBSQL',
                'Server=ServerName;Database=DatabaseName;UID=Username;Pwd=Password;',
                N'EXEC stored_procedure_name @param1 = 1, @param2 = 11');
```

I get this error:

> The metadata could not be determined because statement 'INSERT INTO #Temp.....' in procedure 'stored_procedure_name' uses a temp table.

Can you please suggest a solution, or any other way to call a stored procedure and retrieve only one column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The metadata could not be determined because statement 'insert into](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36151220/2029983)

Comment: Thank you for your response, no it will not work, it's not the same error, in my case the stored procedure i'm calling, it contains a temporary table, i think that's why this error occurred.

Comment: *"in my case the stored procedure i'm calling, it contains a temporary table"* That is ***exactly*** what the link duplicate 's scenario is... From the error in the linked duplicate *"`The metadata could not be determined because statement 'INSERT INTO #Per SELECT ...... uses a temp table.".`. Emhases on  **`uses a temp table`**.

Comment: All right, so please could you suggest another solution, and just to let you know that i can't edit the stored procedure code.

Comment: `INSERT` all the columns into a table, then, and then just `SELECT` the ones you need. The *real* problem here is you're trying to treat a Procedure like a table, when it's not. You don't "`SELECT`" from a Procedure, you `EXECUTE` it.

Comment: Yes i agree with you, i already have a version that insert all columns to a table and select only the id, the issue here is that the developer that wrote the procedure sometimes he changes the returned results so from my side i need to change the temporary table definition too, that's why i'm trying to find a solution to get only one column (ID) from the stored procedure, thank you in advance

Comment: Then you need to change your process at the same time. When the SP is updated, then objects that reference that object should be updated downstream too. That's just a good development cycle. This is smelling more and more strongly of a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: All right, thank you Larnu, so if i understand from what you said is that i can't retrieve only one column while the temporary table inside the stored procedure.

Comment: I'm saying you can't use `OPENROWSET` against a Stored Procedure that contains a Temporary Table. If you *must* use `OPENROWSET` you have to remove the temporary tables from the Procedure. But the real solution here is to ensure changes are propagated downstream.

Comment: All right now i understand more you response now, so please is there any other solutions without using OPENROWSET or storing the returned values into a temporary table ?

Comment: Like i said, stop trying to treat a Stored Procedure like a table, it's not one.

Comment: Yes i know it's not, i'm just wondring if there is another solution.